# Adjust Memory Limit on bitnami wordpress server (azure)

Tags: memory

I am running a bitnami instance of wordpress on azure.

I came across the following woocommerce warning

> WP memory limit:       40 MB - We recommend setting memory to at least
>   64MB. See: Increasing memory allocated to PHP

As [suggested](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP), I went to my php config file

```
/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php
```

I changed the limit as follows:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

The Woo commerce error persists but I have lot of free memory

```
top - 19:51:34 up 14 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.03, 0.05
Tasks: 261 total,   1 running, 260 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.2 us,  0.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.2 id,  0.5 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   7138096 total,  1576576 used,  5561520 free,   119584 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.   301392 cached Mem
```

Any ideas what the problem is?  Why is it not using the memory

Comment: Have you checked how much memory PHP is being allocated? (php-info will tell you). If that's restricted to something less than what you grant WP, I suspect (not 100% sure) that this will prevent WP from getting the amount of memory you're granting it in the wp-config.php.